# Debian DEB package replace config files

Tags: debian

I created a custom debian package which needs to replace certain configuration files like /etc/ssh/sshd.conf. If these files exist it does not replace them.
What is the best way from a deb package to force overwrite these files (if it's possible without a question).

Thanks

Comment: Using packages to distribute configuration files may seem a good initial approach to configuration management, but most of us found that using actual configuration management tooling is much better for the long term.

Answer (score 2):

First: Don't do that. Configuration files are expected to belong to only one package. Better use some configuration management.

If you really want to do it anyway, you likely need to use `dpkg-divert` in the maintainer scripts (`preinst`, `postrm`, etc.) to rename the original configuration file. See the maintainer scripts of grml's `grml-etc-core` package for an example:

- [preinst](https://github.com/grml/grml-etc-core/blob/master/debian/preinst)
- [postrm](https://github.com/grml/grml-etc-core/blob/master/debian/postrm)

Once again: Despite `dpkg-divert` is used above (for a live CD) to "overwrite" conffiles, it's not expected to work that way either, so expect that it may fail under some obscure conditions.

Comment: Can anyone suggest any specific configuration management tools to do it better?  The use case is to install a package, or something like it, that needs to change the default configuration of other packages.